# Multi-Distro boot DVD with SystemRescueCD 2.8.0 fails to boot the SRCD portion

Tags: boot, mount, grub, iso, dvd

I am trying to create a 'multi-distro' 'multi-boot' DVD image containing (amongst others) the [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) ISO.

I am using GRUB as the boot loader and I have managed to get most of the other ISOs booting fine (testing in VirtualBox before I burn to disc). But the RescueCD ISO fails to boot fully and just drops me out to a mini console.

It starts to load the kernel image and `initram.igz` OK, then after it prompts for the `keymap` it attempts to locate the `sysrcd.dat` file (which contains the file system image) by trying to mount `/dev/sr0` and `/dev/sd0` but this is the wrong place. I need it to mount `/dev/scd0` -- the .dat file is located in `/distro/systemrescuecd` on the CD image.

Does anyone please know what file I need to edit to correct the mount paths and/or what command(s) can I append to the kernel load string in GRUB to point it at the right folder/mount point?

Comment: From the manual, you might try the 'isoloop=XX.iso' as a temp fix.

Comment: Hey warl0ck thanks, I had seen that in the SRCD documentation. I tried it earlier but it didn't work for me, just tried it again though and it worked fine! I must have missed something before (I blame bleary eyed frustration). Guess there wasn't any need for me to unpack the ISOs after all! Oh well, at least it works now. Thanks dude